# SendMessage php_serial_class: sms begins with an empty row, the second row begins with ">" symbol

Tags: php, sms, serial-port

I'm using php_serial_class and php to send SMS with a simple code like this:

But the received sms begins with an empty row and the second row begins with ">" symbol, like:

> "
>
> '>Rel1 lock"

(symbol ' must be removed to a proper understanding in this site)

```
include "php_serial.class.php";

$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyS2");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

$serial->sendMessage("ATZ\n\r");
// Wait and read from the port
//$read = $serial -> readPort();

$serial->sendMessage("ATE0\n\r");
// Wait and read from the port
//$read = $serial -> readPort();

// To write into
$serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgf=1;+cnmi=2,1,0,1,0\n\r");//
$serial->sendMessage("AT+cmgs=\"+7912_____\"\n\r");
$serial->sendMessage("Rel1 lock\n\r");
$serial->sendMessage(chr(26));

//wait for modem to send message
sleep(7);
$read=$serial->readPort();

$serial->deviceClose();
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to use `\n\r` for new lines?

Comment: replace "\n\r" to "\r\n" or "\r" - the same effect

Comment: Surely it should be sendMessage(""Rel1 lock"\n\r") ?

Comment: I should receive the Rel1 lock message

Comment: I mean, don't you need another set of "" when you're posting the message string ?

Comment: don't need, I did this a lot of time through the terminal. But if I write $serial->sendMessage("'Rel1 lock'\n\r"); I simply got the same result but in '_'